# Sending unique player name to server not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I'm trying to send a client's unique player name to its respective player object on the server so that both client player and server player have the same unique name but it's not working. Currently when I run this script the player's name on the server is blank. This script is attached to my player prefab. How do I get this to work?

```
public override void OnStartLocalPlayer()
{
    Guid playerUniqueGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    CmdSendNameToServer("Player_" + playerUniqueGuid);
}

[Command]
private void CmdSendNameToServer(string name)
{
    gameObject.transform.name = name;
}
```

Comment: Why have `name` as a parameter if you dont use it at all and instead reference the private class field?

Comment: @maccettura how about now?